# Empty HTTP Response Using http.Client.Do in Golang

Tags: http, go

I am using Go to make an HTTP GET request to an external web service. For some reason, the body of the response is always empty; the content length is always zero bytes. The response status code is always 200, however, and the call to Client.Do returns no error. The request requires an Authorization header, so I am using the http.NewRequest / http.Client.Do pattern to submit the request, as you'll see below. I have done requests similar to these in the past, but never using a GET that required a header. It seems unlikely that this the cause, but I wonder if it may be related. If anyone can spot any potential issues with the pattern used or perhaps has had a similar experience, I'd really appreciate any help.

Thank you.

```
if req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://api.molt.in/v1/orders/11111111/items", nil); err != nil {
    return nil, err
} else {
    client := &http.Client{}
    req.Header.Add("Authorization", "secretToken")

    if resp, err := client.Do(req); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    } else {
        defer resp.Body.Close()
        return readBody(resp.Body)
    }
}
```

Comment: If there is no error, and the response is 200, what is the problem? There's no requirement for a response to have a body. BTW, you generally want to avoid nested if-else when you have the option to return early; most people would write this like: https://play.golang.org/p/q0x8cNvrYw

Comment: Have you checked `resp.ContentLength`? What does `readBody` do?

Comment: What is the result when you perform the same request with curl ?

Comment: You need to specify the type of the Authorization you are trying to do `Bearer` in this case I think that might be the problem, so the header will be `Authorization: Bearer MY_SUPER_SECRET_TOKEN`

Comment: Sorry I didn't give you a full proper example on my latest comment, something like:

```
req.Header.Add("Authorization", fmt.Sprintf("Bearer %s", "secretToken"))

```

Comment: @JimB, you are correct, however, I am expecting a response body in this particular case. The output from a similar call made using cURL returns the data seen [here](http://pastebin.com/GhkNn01t)

With respect to general convention, I appreciate Go's support of variable declaration inline with a conditional. It makes for a subtly more concise code.

Comment: @Ainar-G resp.ContentLength is consistently 0. _readyBody_ uses bufio.NewScanner to extract the contents of the response ultimately instance a struct with it.

Comment: Thank you @ZoT. I believe you may be onto something, but wouldn't a bad authorization header typically result in a 400/401 response status? I will try your suggestion and update you.

Comment: @ZoT I tried updating the Authorization header as you suggested. The change had no impact on the application. Interestingly, it also had no affect while using cURL. The server appears to handle the header the same regardless of whether or not the term "Bearer" is included.

Comment: Correction to the original post: the content length of the response is actually -1, not 0 as originally reported.

Answer (score 1):

I finally discovered the source of the problem. It had nothing to do with the request being made, or the response being received. It had to do with the parsing of the response.

I was using bufio.NewScanner.Text to attempt to convert the response body into a string. Replacing this call with one to ioutil.ReadAll output the string that I originally expected.

Thanks for all of your help, and apologies for the misleading question.